# jQuery before and after photo slide effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, slider, effect

I'm making a before and after image slider like on this page:

http://upstairsweb.com/Examples/slide-bar-example.html

But I would like to have the slider already halfway the image when you visit the page. How can I accomplish this? What code do I need to add? I don't have a lot of work experience with JavaScript so hopefully someone can help me with this.

Here is the tutorial I'm following:

http://upstairsweb.com/blog/basic-jquery-beforeafter-photo-slide-bar

Comment: Please put your working code up on jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this code:

```
$(".topImage").css('width', '50%');
```

Look here http://jsfiddle.net/sbxmal/4fZWA/

Comment: Nice! Thanks a million!